# is it guaranteed that threads will resume in the order they were suspended/blocked by wait() in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Suppose my program uses three threads. The first two threads are blocked using `wait()`, then the third thread comes and resumes both of them. When the third thread frees the two threads, it creates a race condition between those two threads (please correct me if I am wrong). Here is a program I wrote to illustrate this:

```
class Callee {
    static boolean doBlock = true;
    void callMe (int index) throws InterruptedException {
        //suspend the first two threads
        if (index < 3 && doBlock) {
            wait();
        }

        System.out.println("The index is: " + index);

        //let the third thread resume both of them
        if (index == 3) {
            doBlock = false;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

class Caller implements Runnable {

    final int threadIndex;
    final Thread thread;
    final Callee callee;

    Caller(int index, Callee c) {
        threadIndex = index;
        callee = c;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (callee) {
            try {
                callee.callMe(threadIndex);

            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Callee c = new Callee();

        Caller caller1 = new Caller (1, c);
        Caller caller2 = new Caller (2, c);
        Caller caller3 = new Caller (3, c);

        caller1.thread.join();
        caller2.thread.join();
        caller3.thread.join();
    }
}
```

Each time I run the above program on my Windows machine, I get consistent output:

`The index is: 3
 The index is: 1
 The index is: 2`

Note that the first thread was freed before the second thread. Also note that I did not set priorities to any of those threads. I ran it at least ten times but results are not changing. I'm curious if it's my OS or does Java always resume the thread that was blocked first?

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: So are you saying it was just a co-incidence or only windows does it?

Comment: Yes, it was coincidence. I mean, there's only so many ways to arrange 3 things. Or, maybe it's deterministic on your platform; but that's not the same as a guarantee.

Comment: Might be worth looking into `CountdownLatch`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: finally, I got this order - ...is 3, 2, 1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

No, there is no guarantee that they will resume in order so you shouldn't build any logic based on that even if the behavior was validated multiple time by multiple people, but you had a great idea of asking instead of just assuming.

## Long answer

What could be happening is that this is how threads behave on Windows specifically; if the threading is fully handled by the SO itself, it might even be a behavior specific to your specific version of Windows. In that case, because Java works on multiple OS and each OS could behave differently, then Java cannot guarantee a behavior across all environments and therefore makes no promises about it.

It could also just be a behavior of that specific version of the JVM and Sun/Oracle never wanted to commit to a specific behavior, this means that even if this behavior was to be constant in the current JVM version, because it was never part of the formal "contract" they could reserve the right to change it at any moment without prior notification.

In either cases, what could happen if you decide to build logic on top of it is that the code simply wouldn't work properly on another OS or, even better, stop working properly after an OS update or JVM update (even minor ones).

An example of that happened in a company I've worked for a few years back; it used to be that Oracle (the RDBMS) used to automatically sort your results by your GROUP BY criteria if you didn't specify any (it was never part of the SQL standard, nor ever specified in any Oracle document, everyone just noticed it worked like that) ... in their infinite wisdom, many people started just skipping the ORDER BY clause if they used group by. Then came a new Oracle version (might have been 9i or 10g) and they just stopped auto-sorting the results which resulted in millions of $$$ being wasted going over ALL applications to inspect the code and then re-doing test (tests were not automated of course).

Answer (score 0):

No it is not guaranteed unless you use a [fair lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock(boolean))  with a [condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) rather than a `wait/notify`. 
The lock you obtain by `synchronized` is not fair.